# MySQL workbench - overriding tlsVersion

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Am using mysql workbench version 6.3.10. Getting the error below on trying to make a mysql connetion.

```
Access denied for user 'test'@'test.com' (using password: YES). TLS version tlsv1.1 is not in the list of allowed versions tlsv1.2 specified by the tls_version system variable.
```

How to set the tlsVersion to 1.2 in the mysql workbench connection.
This can be set in the JDBC URL as below.

> jdbc:mysql://host:3306/test?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2